# WhatsApp click-to-chat button not starting chat

Tags: url, whatsapp

I have click-to-chat button

```
<a href={`https://wa.me/00359877645533/?text="Hello"`}>
  <img src="/whatsapp.svg"/>
</a>
```

When I click it on my phone it triggers the app, but then "the link couldn't be opened. Check the link and try again". From my understanding, the number format must begin with "00", followed by the country code. On desktop it launches the app, but not chat.

Answer (score 0):

The number format must be country-code + number.
The "00" must be removed from the sample code you used, i.e.:

```
<a href={`https://wa.me/359877645533/?text="Hello"`}>
  <img src="/whatsapp.svg"/>
</a>
```